# How to make a comment in facebook with attached picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

In facebook site you able to make a `comment` and attach image to it. Is it possible to do the same things with facebook api?

I have read this [facebook for dev link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/) and there is no answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation properly, it says-

> **message** is the only parameter in this API call. It should be a string containing the comment text.

So, using the API you can just comment a message to the object using-

```
POST /{object-id}/comments?
   message='This is my message'
```

, no link/picture could be attached alongwith.

Comment: It is true - the API doesn't give 1:1 ratio of the functionality that the actual site does. There are simply things that the API can not do that are possible as a normal user browsing the site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a recent change in the way Facebook handles this, but if I put the complete url in the comment, Facebook detects it as an image and shows it there (along with the url).
Maybe it's not the cleanest way, but it's a way.